# Accessing private web applications on server (running on server's network i.e. not publically accessbile on www ) through public interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, principalcontext

I have a scenario where 2 Web-Applications are running on Server's IIS and accessible on local network. I have to create a public interface (Web) for these websites so that users can access these from their homes.

Work so far:
Using **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement PrincipalContext** i have so far authenticated network users through public application.

Now i am stuck on how to Display/embed Local Web-Applications in this Public application. (something that replicates Iframe functionality but for server side local sites?)

Answer (score 0):

Your public application will have a UI container that your public application's action handler will populate (assuming that you are using asp.net mvc). Since your public server can access the server local to its network, you can use HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse available in .NET to get the response html of the pages and embed it in the display area. So your public server acts in the middle as a medium of communication. You can return different kind of ActionResult objects (such as pdfs, images and other media) and stream them into your display area via your public server.﻿